# Safe and sound usage

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms

I am wondering if a phrase "safe and sound" is used or at least can be used when it isn't referring to person. For example sentences

> They will do anything to keep their bonuses safe and sound!
>
> My feelings are safe and sound, don't you worry.

Are they correct? Thank you.

Comment: As adjectives, 'safe' means 'protected' and 'sound' means 'in good condition'.  Both are fine for inanimate as well as animate objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer “safe and sound” as non-human objects.

Another example:

> My cat is safe and sound

Non-living objects can be referred to as well.

Examples:

> My money is safe and sound in the bank
>
> My keys are safe and sound on my desk

Comment: I am mainly interested in sentences including "non-living" objects. E.g. My wallet is safe and sound in my pocket. I admit it might not be clear since I mentioned "person"/\.

Comment: @Bendom I see, edited post